# RVIZ start specific config file

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.

I am just wondering if is it possible to configure RViz such that when I start it, it will start automatically with a specific config file.

In advance thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76864/rviz-start-specific-config-file/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-09-05

Post score: 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

well, I found out that saving the configuration as a default.rviz, next time I open it, it will automatically load the configuration :)

---

Originally posted by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) with karma: 556 on 2013-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-05-01**:
That's only valid when you're using the same machine (+ same user account) since the config last time is saved into `~/.rviz`. For more robustness, use @Tones's suggestion or create a `.launch`.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-16**:
What if I have changed user and want to edit the default config? Is there a way to do that?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-07-16**:
@kipr please refrain from asking a new question in `comment` area (forum contributors won't find it as a new question easily). Please open a new question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the command line parameter `-d <arg>` at startup. `<arg>` is the path to your .vcg-file:

```
rosrun rviz rviz -d <arg>
```

---

Originally posted by [Tones](https://answers.ros.org/users/3551/tones/) with karma: 635 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 31

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a launch file:

```
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find my_pkg)/path_to_config/config.rviz"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) with karma: 212 on 2021-11-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Divelix](https://answers.ros.org/users/77896/divelix/) on 2022-02-18**:
How can I do the same from command line (find package specifically)?